# I have two UIViewControllers that I need to compare to see if they are the same subclass of UIViewController

Tags: swift, class, comparison

How do I check if two UIViewController subclassed objects have the same subclass?

Comment: Do you think of `if let vc1 as? TheSubclass, vc2? as TheSubclass { ... }`, or are you looking for a generic solution where you don't even know the subclass?

Comment: I was comparing two subclasses, so type(of: vc1) == type(of: vc2) would have been the correct implementation, but I ended up taking a more elegant approach I found in my code. I am sure I will find use for this in the future though. I find that more often then not having to type check is a bad way to implement code. It is similar to a child vc having knowledge of it's parent vc in theory. Anyhow thanks for everyone's time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3 you can compare object's types with **type(of:)** method:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {

}

class VC2: UIViewController {

}

let vc1 = VC1()
let vc2 = VC2()

let typeComparisonResult = type(of: vc1) == type(of: vc2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw typeof(vc1), but I didn't see the swift 3 version. It was harder to find this answer then I thought it would be, but I solved what I needed to do in code either way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Swift allows class comparison by using the `is` keyword. For example, if you have `class a` and `class b` that are both subclassing UIViewController. Then you can confirm this using the is keyword.

```
class a:UIViewController
{

}

class b:UIViewController
{

}

let instanceA:a = a()
let instanceB:b = b()

if a is UIViewController && b is UIViewController
{
    print("Both are subclasses of UIViewController")
}
```